# Communication between inherited classes

Tags: c++, inheritance, class, object, communication

I have 3 classes in different files:

```
   X
   |
-------
|     |
Y     Z
```

I will be creating several objects of inherited classes Y and Z.

A specific function in class Z should be executed only if some **flag** variable is set by class Y.

Where should I create this flag variable (which class) and what should be the declaration be like (static/extern)?

Comment: Could you tell us more about X, Y, and Z?  Your problem statement is clear, but it's very hard to understand why only Ys would be able to set the flag that only Zs could read.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider [template method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method) as a replacement for the infamous flags.

Answer (score 1):

The flag should be in Z, if it's only Z that's effected by it. But the whole thing smells - flags being set by classes rather than instances. Use polymorphism rather than flags where practical.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a weird design; you will create dependencies between inherited classes.

The method (and flag variable) should be in the parent class X.

(edit)
to refine/replace what I wrote above, 
the variable could be in the base class, the Y class will set the variable (Setter) and the Z class will have the method which will "Get" the value from the base class.

Answer (score 0):

Best answer: what Anton Gogolev says, use templates.

(Else use a private enum variable. Use for example: GetType() which returns type.x/type.y etc)

Answer (score 0):

What if you have two Y objects, and only one has the flag set? Which of your three Z objects are affected? The question suggests your design is flawed.